# Apache not showing a test page when I browse to the server running it

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I have set up a CentOS 5.5 server with Apache on it. The `httpd` service starts just fine (no warnings at all), and I was under the impression that I should see an Apache test page if I was to browse to the server via Firefox or the like (not localley, from a different machine), when no virtual hosts exist?

I have set the `HOSTNAME` entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network`, added the FQDN to `/etc/hosts`, and set the `ServerName` in `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (`DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html`).

Is there anything I have missed, or am I barking up the wrong tree completly? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to open test page? Any chance that iptables is blocking requests on server with httpd?

Comment: Sorry Andrei, not sure what you mean? Server is called monitor, with IP 192.168.1.16, and have tried both `http://monitor` and `http://192.168.1.16`, both of which show the standard 'Unable to display your webpage' error. Is that what you meaning? Thanks.

Comment: What does `netstat -plnt |grep httpd` output?

Comment: Can you get to any other services on the machine? SSH for instance.

Comment: Did you open port 80 in your firewall?

Comment: look in the apache log /var/log/apache2/ I imagine

Comment: check /var/log/httpd/error.log and /var/log/httpd/access.log

Answer (score 2):

You say you're getting "webpage cannot be displayed", not "server cannot be reached", so I think that Apache is responding on port 80, but check to see if something like `wget http://localhost/` (or `links http://localhost`) gives you something different. If so, you have a firewall issue. Do you have iptables enabled, and are you blocking port 80? If so, edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` to allow port 80 access, and then `service iptables restart`.

Assuming Apache IS responding on port 80 to other computers...

CentOS shows the welcome page for an empty vhost directory by default when you:

1. Have the `Include conf.d/*.conf` line in httpd.conf.
2. Have an `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` that contains:

   Options -Indexes
       ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
3. And `/var/www/error/noindex.html` exists and is readable by the webserver.

So, I would check all three of those things, once you're sure Apache is responding on port 80.